# Passing Json data from Controller to View in Angular JS to build a table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

Trying to get the certain fields to display, ideally in a table (headings, rows & columns). And looking for a best way find fields in a Json feed. I tried using the controller to find the fields then pass that data to the view in the HTML.

Is there something wrong in the controller with respect to the Json? the fields are empty. Seems like nothing is passed from the controller to the view ?  This is what I tried:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app" >
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>LIVE</title>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('DataCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

 $scope.result = {
                  "data": {
                    "transactionList": [{
                      "barcode": "52905819992681",
                      "training": 0,
                      "tranNo": 1,
                      "userId": "8796093054980",
                      "retailerId": "defaultRetailer",
                      "storeId": "12Store",
                      "deviceId": "afd03463-9ee7-45d4-9d2e-8d64a683f126",
                      "tillId": "2",
                      "tranTypeId": "regularSale",
                      "isTranVoid": 0,
                      "totalItems": 1,
                      "merchTotal": 50.0,
                      "promoTotal": 0.0
                    }, {
                      "barcode": "52905819592681",
                      "training": 0,
                      "tranNo": 1,
                      "userId": "8796093054980",
                      "retailerId": "defaultRetailer",
                      "storeId": "23Store",
                      "deviceId": "afd03463-9ee7-45d4-9d2e-8d64a683f126",
                      "tillId": "2",
                      "tranTypeId": "regularSale",
                      "isTranVoid": 0,
                      "totalItems": 1,
                      "merchTotal": 50.0,
                      "promoTotal": 0.0
                    }]
                  }
                }

};

$scope.elements = $scope.result.data.transactionList.map(function (res) {
  var e = {};
  e.transTypeId = res.transTypeId;
  e.userId = res.userId;
  e.storeId = res.storeId;
  return e;
});

});

    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="DataCtrl">
<h1>Live from the JSON feed</h1>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="e in elements">
        {{ e.transTypeId}}: {{ e.userId }}, {{ e.storeId }}
    </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a extra `}` in your `$scope.result`. It should be like:

```
$scope.result = {
                  "data": {
                    "transactionList": [{
                      "barcode": "52905819992681",
                      "training": 0,
                      "tranNo": 1,
                      "userId": "8796093054980",
                      "retailerId": "defaultRetailer",
                      "storeId": "12Store",
                      "deviceId": "afd03463-9ee7-45d4-9d2e-8d64a683f126",
                      "tillId": "2",
                      "tranTypeId": "regularSale",
                      "isTranVoid": 0,
                      "totalItems": 1,
                      "merchTotal": 50.0,
                      "promoTotal": 0.0
                    }, {
                      "barcode": "52905819592681",
                      "training": 0,
                      "tranNo": 1,
                      "userId": "8796093054980",
                      "retailerId": "defaultRetailer",
                      "storeId": "23Store",
                      "deviceId": "afd03463-9ee7-45d4-9d2e-8d64a683f126",
                      "tillId": "2",
                      "tranTypeId": "regularSale",
                      "isTranVoid": 0,
                      "totalItems": 1,
                      "merchTotal": 50.0,
                      "promoTotal": 0.0
                    }]
                  }
                };

// get rid of this};
```

Here is working [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/EsWuxhIUOuSD1wvHTUOt?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks -- was getting lost with the }; and the }

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a `};` too many?

Automatic indentation usually makes those kinds of errors apparent.

Comment: Thanks -- was getting lost with the }; and the }

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but you are trying to read json data directly without parsing it?
[MDN JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Also it would be nice if you upload your code on something like http://jsfiddle.net
This way people can test it out.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use ng-model="...", it gives you the opportunity to overwrite an attribute or to show it. You can try it with

```
<input type="number" ng-model="someID" disabled="disabled">
```

*disabled if u need readOnly on that field. 
and see how it works, maybe it can help you out.
regards